# How to find Pause/Play service or characteristic being sent between 2 devices

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy

This is my very first post on this wonderful forum.  So please pardon my ignorance.  I am trying to develop a hardware with embedded software that can communicate via BLE.  I am trying to make the hardware control an App to play, pause, volume up, or volume down from certain buttons that are on the hardware piece.  However, the App is on a phone (this could be any App, iTunes, YouTube, etc).  But I am not successful in finding the service>characteristic that will help me in sending it from the hardware piece to the App on the phone to control it according the above commands.
This might be a bigger problem that I am not aware, or it could be something minor that I am missing so please any help or advice is greatly appreciated.  I did visit the Bluetooth.com site and went over the specification multiple times, but being new to the BLE software development, its not easy and very straightforward.  So please if anyone can assist with this matter, I will be very thankful.  I am not expecting anyone to spoon feed me the information, but any advice that can get me on the right tracks will help in great deal.

Thanks once again and hope to hear from someone.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are searching for the [Audio/Video Remote Control Profile (AVRCP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Audio/Video_Remote_Control_Profile_(AVRCP)). The [Bluetooth SIG](https://www.bluetooth.com/) host the corresponding specification [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/a-v-remote-control-profile-1-6-2/).

Comment: Hi Risto. Thank you so much for your answer. I will definitely look into this link you provided and let you know.  Thanks again.  Really appreciate it.